# extjs 4.1 pagingtoolbar displays correctly but grid loads all records

Tags: coldfusion, extjs4.1, coldfusion-9

Okay, so I've been at this all day and can't figure out why the grid is loading all records instead of the pageSize: 25 limit I configured on the store. The paging toolbar is rendering the correct pages, but the grid is what is autoloading all records. I'm thinking it is because of the way my controller is loading the view. I have my .cfc server side processing setup correctly using the paging_on, start, limit, sort and dir in my arguments. If anyone can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my controller:

```
onAccountActivityListAfterrender: function(pnl, eOpts) {
    var store = this.getStore("AccountSessions");
    store.load({
        params : {
            start : 0,
            limit : 25
        },
        callback: function (recs, op, success) {
            if (!success) {
                Ext.Msg.alert("Error!", op.error[0].ERROR);
            }
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('pnl-accountactivity-list');
            grid.getStore().add(store.getRange());
            this.showApp(pnl);
        },
        scope: this
    });
},
```

and here is my store:

```
Ext.define("EXAMPLE.store.AccountSessions", {
alias: "store.AccountSessions",
extend: "Ext.data.Store",
model: "EXAMPLE.model.AccountSession",
pageSize: 25,
proxy: {
    api: {
        create  : undefined,
        read    : "ajax/account.cfc?method=account_sessions",
        update  : undefined,
        destroy : undefined
    },
    extraParams: { 
        account_id: account
     },                             
    reader: {
        messageProperty: "ERRORS",
        root: "DATA",
        successProperty: "SUCCESS",
        totalProperty: "TOTAL",
        type: "json"
    },
    type: "ajax"
}
```

});

Comment: Please, is there anyone out there that can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to show the server-side codes.
Make sure the values that returned correctly~